# Chatgpt API Dot problem - CHATGPT api issue

Tags: openai-api

I'm facing an interesting situation. I prepared a google collab code that translates the language of the columns in excel using the chatgpt api.

```
def Cevirifunk3(soru):
    messages = [
        {"role": "system", "content": "translate this question from turkish to english"},
        {"role": "user", "content": soru}
    ]

    completion = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0125",
        messages=messages
    )

    return completion.choices[0].message.content
```

With pandas, I take the data from Excel, translate it here and save it again. I did not have any problems with many data. but in certain questions it doesn't send the question before the question to the chatgpt api.

for example question is = "The gleam of a copper bowl in my eyes, The sound of neighbors' footsteps in my ears, Even if no one gives me a sip of water again, Even if someone at my bedside tells me there is no water. Which of the following is the main emotion of this poem? A) Regret B) Pride C) Longing"

The question is not in English, I translated it for clarity.

when I send this question to the function, the answer I get is as follows. before the question stem is not translated.

"What is the main emotion of this poem? A) Regret B) Pride C) Longing"

but when I remove the dot in front of the question stem, the translation works the way I want.

......tells me there is no water (. this dot must be removed for right answer) Which of the following is the main emotion of this poem?......

I have about 1200 data. It is not possible to go through them one by one. why am I having this problem? how can I overcome it?

I tried to convert it to string. I tried utf8 encoding. I tried to define and send the question directly from google collaba, not from excel.